# ADB do not recognize a Tegra Based Tablet

Tags: adb, usb-drivers, tegra

I have a tablet and I'd like to use adb but I have some probles, I looked on google but without luck...

**Tablet Info: (from tablet)**

```
Model Nr: SN10T1
Android OS Version: 2.2
TapUI Version: 1.2-4204
Kernel Version: 2.6.32.9-0001
Build Nr: FRF91
```

I did the following:

- Activate Debug Usb on tablet
- Downloaded and installed android-sdk and google-usb-driver
- Edited the file `extras/google/usb_driver/android_winusb.inf` adding under `[Google.NTx86]` and `[Google.NTamd64]`

  `;NVIDIA Tegra`

  `%SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0955&PID_7000`

  `%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0955&PID_7100&MI_01`

Restarted adb but using adb devices it does not show the tablet....

I checked under device manager the VID and PID of my device and VID = 0955, PID = 7100 so they are the same of the file above...

Triyng to reinstall the driver using `extras/google/usb_driver/android_winusb.inf` I got this error:

`The folder you specified doesn't contain a compatible software driver for your device. If the folder contains a driver, make sure it's designed to works with  Windows x64 based system`

I have windows 7 64bit Professional...

Comment: Have you looked for drivers from the manufacturer?

Comment: I can't find the driver... if they exist

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/enable-adb-usb-drivers-for-nvidia-tegra-based-android-tablets). 
I just followed them (changing the PID and VID numbers as you did and it worked!)

**TIPS**

1. In the changed `.inf` file remember leaving an empty line after pasting the code after [Google.NTx86] or [Google.NTamd64]; and also after it and the beginning of the next paragraph.
2. Don't forget the step 5 where you must put your VID number (example: if your VID  is 0955, then put 0x955).

And the rest is exactly the same. It worked for an Excite 10 from Toshiba with Tegra 3 processor.